# How can I optimize this code to display custom fields?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, custom-fields

I am displaying several custom fields for Woocommerce products:

```
function fields() {

global $product;

$value1 = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'storage', true );
$value2 = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'delivery_date', true );
$value3 = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'mpn', true );
$value4 = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'color', true );
$value5 = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'sizes_available', true );
$value6 = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'country_of_origin', true );

if ( ! empty( $value1 ) ) {
echo '<div>Storage: '  . $value1 . '</div>';
}

if ( ! empty( $value2 ) ) {
echo '<div>Delivery: '  . $value2 . '</div>';
}

if ( ! empty( $value3 ) ) {
echo '<div>Manufacturer's product number: '  . $value3 . '</div>';
}

if ( ! empty( $value4 ) ) {
echo '<div>Color: '  . $value4 . '</div>';
}

if ( ! empty( $value5 ) ) {
echo '<div>Sizes: '  . $value5 . '</div>';
}

if ( ! empty( $value6 ) ) {
echo '<div>Country: '  . $value6 . '</div>';
}

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'fields', 10 );
```

How can I optimize/shorten this code? There might be even more custom fields in the future to be added, so there must be a way to clean up this code?

**EDIT** to clarify.

Comment: This question belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com. You can better use a loop.

Comment: Please don't post questions and then change the content when someone answers.  It wastes yours and others time as they have to keep on updating answers as you change your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I would recommend to solve the problem in this way:

- Create an array of fields
- Create a loop
- Use special variables `$label` and `$value` for decreasing code line length
- Use `printf` to control and format values to display
- Escape with `esc_html` to avoid conflicting field value and `HTML` code.

### The code snippet:

```
global $product;

$fields = [
    [ 'label' => 'Storage', 'name' => 'storage' ],
    [ 'label' => 'Delivery', 'name' => 'delivery_date' ],
    [ 'label' => "Manufacturer's product number", 'name' => 'mpn' ],
    [ 'label' => 'Color', 'name' => 'color' ],
    [ 'label' => 'Sizes', 'name' => 'sizes_available' ],
    [ 'label' => 'Country', 'name' => 'country_of_origin' ],
];

foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
    $label = $field['label'];
    $value = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), $field['name'], true );

    printf( '<div>%s: %s</div>', esc_html( $label ), esc_html( $value ) );
}
```